# Matching a needle at beginning of a haystack line with stripos().

Tags: php

In the following code:

```
// array source elements are formatted like...
// string=string 
// string string=string

foreach ($matches[0] as $value){ 

    $titleText = array(); // Store results into an array.

    foreach ($lines as $line) { // Read the lines in the dictionary file 

        if ( stripos($line, "<beginning of a line>" . $value . "=") || stripos($line, " " . $value . "=") !== false){ // Found string in array.
            list($field1, $field2) = explode('=', $line);
            array_push($titleText, "$field1 > $field2"); // Store all finds in array before outputting.
        } 

    }

echo "Found " . count($titleText) . " instances of " . $value . "\n";

print_r($titleText);

}
```

I'm trying to get stripos() to recognise the beginning of a line, here...

```
if ( stripos($line, "<beginning of a line>" . $value . "=") || stripos($line, " " . $value . "=") !== false)
```

...but can't figure out if this is possible. Is there a way with stripos or perhaps there is another function which will do this better. I originally chose stripos because the array is quite large and stripos was meant to be the fastest/least resource intensive.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`stripos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php) returns the position where the start of a match is found (as an integer), or `false` if no match was found.
Just check if a matching result was found, starting from position 0 (beginning of the string).

```
if ( stripos($line, $value . "=") === 0 || stripos($line, " " . $value . "=") !== false)
```

where the result of `stripos($line, $value . "=")` must be 0 and have the same type of 0, integer. That's what `===` does. Why not just using `==`?

#### Explanation

If the haystack does not contain the needle, the function returns `false`. When converted to an integer, `false` equals `0`. In other words, 'no match' would give us the same result as 'match at beginning of the string'. We don't want that.

`===` checks for equality, including a type check.

- `0 == false`: Same value. TRUE!
- `0 === false`: Same value, *TR*... but hey, different type: FALSE!

Conclusion: it's important using the `===` operator in stead of the `==` one.

Comment: Oops :) sorry, I was editing the answer a bit. Adding some explanations, just to be complete. Aah well, glad it already helped in the first place ;)